# How can I pass a parameter from a view to a controller without having to change the routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have a series of buttons that call the same controller function but each passes a different parameter into the controller.

I have been looking around for a bit and most of the solutions say changing the routing config which I do not want to do.  I am wondering if there is a different way to do it, or which is at least a standard practice.

```
<button class="button">Medium Voltage</button>
@Html.ActionLink("Medium Voltage", "GaugeView", "PSA")

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GaugeView(string LineName)
{
//Do stuff based on which LineName was specified
    return View();
}
```

I would also like to hide the string that is passing into the function but that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the custom value like this:

```
@{
    var url = Url.Action("GaugeView", "PSA", new { LineName = "value"});
}

<button onclick="window.location.href='@url';">Medium Voltage</button>

@Html.ActionLink("Medium Voltage", "GaugeView", "PSA", new { LineName = "value"}, null)
```

Comment: I have tried that and it still shows LineName as null inside the controller.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked for passing in the parameter.  Am I able to use my button styling for the onclick or do I have to restyle the onclick.  I am not well versed in CSS/Html. Nevermind I just have to call the button class. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According document at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

You need to note **routeValues** parameter.

Comment: How would I be able to put that inside the button?  I do not want to have the link showing, I want it to be what happens when the button is clicked.